# Seeking dictionary of French language terms used in Canadian records?

Tags: vital-records, canada, translation

Where can I find a dictionary or list translating French terms used in Canadian records?

I am looking for translations of headers for Birth, Marriage and Death certificates and for land and probate records.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Barbara. Given that I am not an expert in French-Canadian record groups, I find this question overly broad. Translation into what language? Documents are birth, marriage, death, land and probate records from all French-Canadian locations covering all timeframes. In my personal experience, questions asked in the context of an actual problem are more valuable.

Comment: @GeneJ You should reject my proposed edit; I get it now.

Answer (score 5):

I have been researching French-Canadian records for over 25 years.  There are no translations of documents, which were of course written in French. However, Google has a fair translator program and with tweaking it can be a fair translation of the document. Also, there is an online list of researchers specifically for Quebec Research at Rootsweb.  Among the members are several who willingly translate documents.  Check at Rootsweb on how to join their lists, then seek Quebec-Reasearch and join it - it's FREE.  Another option is to find a French-English dictionary.  BMD records are all fairly similar which means that after looking at a few you'll get a feel for what it's saying.  The numbers are difficult if you have no smattering of French - again goggle 'french numbers' and a lot of help comes up with lists of number.  Hope this helps somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

I've needed the same thing, and was unable to find something specifically written for French-Canadian genealogy researchers.

In the past, I've stumbled through with a variety of techniques, everything from my spotty French knowledge, to online translators, to context of the data. For New Brunswick records, I was fortunate to have ancestors that were filled out on French and English documents, which allowed me to go back and forth to figure out the translation.

If you end up making your own dictionary for such terms, please make it available to others and post about it here. I, for one, would make use of it!